# How to use proxy on specific url selenium

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, foxyproxy

I would like to go through a proxy for some urls but not for all when executing my python program. I am a beginner on selenium (and python in general), manually I used foxyproxy on my firefox but automatically thanks to selenium I do not know how to proceed.

Is it possible to switch to a proxy in the middle of the code?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you show us what you already tried? Have a look at [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This increases your chance of getting helpful answers.

Comment: It's not really possible, but you can just launch a new browser.